# My app crashes whn opened up?

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-sdk-2.3

I have this app it says it unexpectedly closed when i open it, here is the main java... where the majority of the work is done, i really need as much help as i can get thank you all in advance

```
package geezer.quiz.app;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import geezer.quiz.app.score;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //---------------
        final TextView aText;
        final TextView bText;
        final TextView cText;
        final TextView dText;
        final TextView question;
        final CheckBox a1;
        final CheckBox b1;
        final CheckBox c1;
        final CheckBox d1;
        final TextView result;
        Button next;


        a1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        b1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        c1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        d1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);

        result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);

        aText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        cText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        dText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.questionText);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        final String a[] = new String[5]; 
        final String b[] = new String[5];
        final String c[] = new String[5];
        final String d[] = new String[5];
        final String questions[]= new String [5];

        a[0] = "Bell Bottoms";
        a[1] = "Far Out";
        a[2] = "Insanity";
        a[3] = "Tye Dye";
        a[4] = "Yes";

        b[0] = "Speedos";
        b[1] = "Solid";
        b[2] = "Calvin Harris";
        b[3] = "Love Beads";
        b[4] = "Maybe";

        c[0] = "Plaid";
        c[1] = "Norm";
        c[2] = "Cobra Starship";
        c[3] = "Bell Bottoms";
        c[4] = "Later";

        d[0] = "Flannel";
        d[1] = "Radical";
        d[2] = "David Guetta";
        d[3] = "Granny Glasses";
        d[4] = "Never";

        questions[0] = "Which is the most in style?";
        questions[1] = "Which term is used most?";
        questions[2] = "Four musical artists are listed, which is fake?";
        questions[3] = "Which of these is the most embarrasing?";
        questions[4] = "If someone proposed you join a Golly Gee club how would you respond?";



         next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {


            score.q ++;

            boolean q1a = false;
            boolean q1b = false;
            boolean q1c = false;
            boolean q1d = false;
            boolean q2a = false;
            boolean q2b = false;
            boolean q2c = false;
            boolean q2d = false;
            boolean q3a = false;
            boolean q3b = false;
            boolean q3c = false;
            boolean q3d = false;
            boolean q4a = false;
            boolean q4b = false;
            boolean q4c = false;
            boolean q4d = false;
            boolean q5a = false;
            boolean q5b = false;
            boolean q5c = false;
            boolean q5d = false;



                    aText.setText(a[score.q]); 
                    bText.setText(b[score.q]);
                    cText.setText(c[score.q]);
                    dText.setText(d[score.q]);

                    question.setText(questions[score.q]); 


                    if(d1.isChecked() && score.q == 0) {
                        q1d = true;
                        score.score++;
                    }


                    if(c1.isChecked() && score.q == 1) {
                        q2c = true;
                        score.score++;
                    }

                    if(a1.isChecked() && score.q == 2) {
                        q3a = true;
                        score.score++;
                    }

                    if(d1.isChecked() && score.q == 3) {
                        q4d = true;
                        score.score++;
                    }


                    if(d1.isChecked() && score.q == 4) {
                        q5d = true;
                        score.score++;

                        if( score.score >2 && score.q == 4){
                             result.setText("You are not a geezer");
                         }
                        if( score.score <3 && score.q == 4){
                             result.setText("You are indeed a geezer");
                         }

                }
            }

         });

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

here is the second java file (score)... i just have two variables in here

```
package geezer.quiz.app;

import geezer.quiz.app.MainActivity;

public class score {



    protected static int score = 0;
    protected static int q =-1;

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }

}
```

here is the logcat, i don't know what any of this means... and i meant to provide this, i am sorry i forgot...

```
07-28 23:45:23.542: D/AndroidRuntime(411): Shutting down VM
07-28 23:45:23.542: W/dalvikvm(411): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{geezer.quiz.app/geezer.quiz.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at geezer.quiz.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  ... 11 more
07-28 23:46:32.822: I/Process(411): Sending signal. PID: 411 SIG: 9
07-28 23:48:24.712: D/AndroidRuntime(420): Shutting down VM
07-28 23:48:24.722: W/dalvikvm(420): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{geezer.quiz.app/geezer.quiz.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1815)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1831)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1024)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at geezer.quiz.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4397)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1779)
07-28 23:48:24.742: E/AndroidRuntime(420):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: We're not just going to debug this for you. What have you done in the way of debugging the problem? How about a stack trace? Anything in logcat? What line of code throws what exception?

Comment: posted logcat, so much wrong i don't know what it all means

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace tells you **exactly** what the problem is:

```
android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

...which means that one of these casts is not valid, because the view you're *trying* to cast to an `EditText` is actually a `TextView`:

```
result = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.result);

aText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
bText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
cText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
dText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
question = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.questionText);
```

It's at `MainActivity.java` line 40, again, as the stack strace tells you:

```
07-28 23:45:23.576: E/AndroidRuntime(411):  at geezer.quiz.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
```